# Orthogonal self-intersection of geodesics

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, vectors, curvature, geodesics

I learnt that geodesics parallel transport their velocity vectors. Does that mean a geodesic cannot intersect itself orthogonally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't see how the implication follows. It is very possible for geodesics to intersect themselves orthogonally, even in 2-dimensional manifolds. One example that is easy to visualize is a [geodesic on an ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid):
[image: 1]

In fact, this is the trajectory of a satellite in low Earth orbit due to the oblateness of the Earth. However, if you consider 4-dimensional spacetime, your statement is true for massive particles as they follow timelike trajectories and two timelike vectors can never be orthogonal to each other. But again, this does not follow from your first statement that "geodesics parallel transport their velocity vectors".

Comment: This was my (probably wrong) understanding: along a geodesic, it's velocity vector never picks up an orthogonal component as it is parallelly transported. At the point of self intersection, there will be two directions for the geodesic's velocity and each will therefore have no components along each other. Is this correct? I am actually a little confused about stuff that happens when geodesics intersect.

Comment: @SX849 Geodesics are specified by providing both a starting point and a starting vector. It is not true that all geodesics passing through a point must have the same tangent vector. Each geodesic parallel transports its own tangent vector. There is no problem here.

Comment: Okay , thanks a lot, I've understood. My doubt was:  if we consider a point of self intersection of a particular geodesic. From this point we parallely transport it's velocity vector along the closed curve, say clockwise and reach this point again. The velocity vector then should not have picked up any normal component and thus the intersection can't be orthogonal?  But the answer is that at the point of self intersection of the geodesic it has two velocity vectors . I hope that this is correct.

Comment: Yes this helps... I will read more about this, thank you very much :) !

Comment: @SX849 I think the point you're missing is that there is no global definition of "normal component". It is true that in a geodesic, the tangent vector gains no normal component, but that is only true at each point. It does not follow that it gains no normal component "overall" (the concept doesn't even exist). Neither does it care about the "history" of the geodesic. The points that it previously passed through are irrelevant. All it does is given the current point and velocity, parallel transport it along itself to obtain the subsequent point and velocity.

Comment: Yes I'm beginning to see clearly the concept. I will read and think more about this and it's connection with Riemann curvature. Thanks again!

Comment: @SX849 Note that the relationship with curvature isn't strict. The 2-sphere has curvature but geodesics, which are great circles, always intersect themselves with the same vector. The cone has zero curvature (except at the tip) but geodesics can intersect in a non-parallel direction. Neither way is true in general